# How to create a Contrast Image as described in Su's binarization paper?

Tags: image-processing

In "[Binarization of Historical Document Images Using the Local Maximum and Minimum](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT6150/Articles/Binarization1.pdf)", Su defines a formula for generating a Contrast Image:

```
D(x,y) = (fMax(x,y) - fMin(x,y)) / (fMax(x,y) + fMin(x,y) + e)
```

Where fMax and fMin are the maximum and minimum intensity pixels of a gray scale image in a 3x3 window for a particular x,y point in a gray scale image, and e is a very small number (ex: 0.0000001) so that the denominator is never 0.

My question is this: How does one use this to actually generate a Contrast Image as described in the paper?  Wont the values always be less than 1?  Since the gray scale image has an integer range from 0 to 255, how can this result in a valid gray scale compliant contrast image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When processing images as doubles or floats, it is very common to rescale them such that all values go between 0 and 1 (1.0 corresponds to a value of 255 if you convert back to integer values). Depending on the language you are using, there may be a function which converts images into this "calculation" format for you (e.g. in MATLAB you can call `im2double()` on your image), or you will need to ensure that you do that conversion yourself (e.g. in Python it is often easier to work with numpy arrays while doing calculations, and if you know the format of the data you are reading in you can easily do this rescaling at the same time you convert).

Comment: thank you.  It seems like I simply need to multiply the formula's value by the range of grayscale values I am using... so in my case, 255.  Is it that simple?  That way: 1 = 255, .5 = 128, 0 = 0, etc.

Comment: Yeah, once you are done all your calculations converting back to integer values is just a case of multiplying all image pixels by 255.